# Void function sending back an array to main, but I can't get the array to output the values correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, function, file-io

I am currently working on a project for one of my classes and we are not permitted to use pointers or vectors (unfortunately), and I cannot get the output right for an array.
  I was given a file that contains 81 rows and 2 columns
(column 1 lists X values, column 2 holds Y values). The first row are the column titles so they are ignored.
  I have to create a function that reads the data into parallel, one dimensional arrays (one for the X values and one for the Y values). I got the function to work properly and if I output the arrays in the same while loop that reads the data from the file all is well. However, when I go back and try to output them in main I just get a bunch of nonsense. 
  Here is my code thus far:

```cpp
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<iomanip>
    using namespace std;

    //Function Prototype for readFile
    void readFile(double oneDforX[], double oneDforY[]);

    //Declare named constant for max number of rows
    const int MAX_ROWS = 100;

    int main()
    {
        //Declare two 1D array to hold data for X and Y
        double oneD_ForXValues[MAX_ROWS];
        double oneD_ForYValues[MAX_ROWS];

        //Call function readFile to fill arrays
        readFile(oneD_ForXValues, oneD_ForYValues);

        /*
            This is where I'm having the problem, when the arrays are 
            sent back to main I can't get the data to output correctly.

            I tried this for the X array:

            for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
            {
                cout << oneD_ForXValues[i] << end;
            }
                **This did not work, my output was something like this:
                3.5    //The last number in the array
                0
                0      //Then a bunch of zeros all the way to the end
                0

                Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!
        */

        return 0;
    }

    //Function Header for readFile function
    void readFile(double oneDforX[], double oneDforY[])
    {
        //Declare file stream object and open file
        ifstream dataIn;
        dataIn.open("dataFile.txt");

        //Loop counter
        int count = 0;

        //If opening file does not fail, execute
        if (!dataIn.fail())
        {
            //Ignore first line, column titles
            dataIn.ignore(80, '\n');

            //While loop to read in data
            while (!dataIn.fail())
            {
                dataIn >> oneDforX[count] >> oneDforY[count];
            }
        }
        //If the file failed to open
        else
        {
            cout << "An error occurred opening the file." << endl;
        }

        //Close the file
        dataIn.close();
    }
    //Back to main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never increment `count` in `readFile`, so you just write to the first element of your arrays over and over.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe I missed that haha.